# How to add id and body to axios.PUT request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am using axios with REACT and wondering how I can use it to make a put request to update an object through the backend node/express API I have set up.

I need to be able to pass an `id` and a `body` and not sure of how to do so.

```
axios.put('/api/profile', id, body)
.then(response => { 

console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(err => { 

console.log(err);
});
```

I do not think this will work as it takes the parameters of `put(url, data, {headers})`

Comment: is id a route parameter? meaning that the actual resolved url is `/api/profile/:id` or is it part of the body?

Comment: I don't have it as a route parameter, but I suppose I could add it on the backend. Would this be the optimal way of doing this?

Comment: It is a common way of doing it.
So you would sd something like  
`axios.put('/api/profile' + id, body) 

then on your server you can define your route this way:

`app.post('/api/profile/:id')`, 

the id will then be available at req.params.id

Comment: What would be the other way to do it without putting it in the route parameter?

Comment: You can put it in a query string but that is a bit odd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern for this is to making an axios request using the id of the entity/item that you want to update and return as shown:

```
    axios.put(`/api/profile/${id}`, body); //using string interpolation
    axios.put('/api/profile' + id, body); //using string concatenation
```

Then, on your express/node backend, you have a route that will match with this request's URI path and update that profile with the body. Not sure what you're using for your DB, but in pseudocode it would look like this:

```js
    /* 
     * 1. query profile Model for the specific profile
     * 2. make sure to check if foundProfile is undefined or not.
     * 3. update profile with body
     * 4. Catch on errors
     */
    router.put('/api/profile/:id', (req, res, next) => {
        Profile.findbyId(req.params.id)
           .then(foundProfile => foundProfile.update(req.body))  
           .catch(next);
    })
```

As mentioned in a comment above, you could do this via the query string, but that would be odd/anti-pattern.